# Jquery show method not working properly in XUL

Tags: jquery, css, xul

I'm trying to create a firefox extension with dynamic XUL and Jquery. When I define an element using

```
<vbox class="b" id="event" style="display:none"></vbox>
```

and when I try with

```
$('.b').show();
```

command, it works fine.

But, When I try defining the element using

```
<vbox class="b" id="event"></vbox>
```

and the style in another .css file with

```
display:none
```

and try to show is using the same Jquery code given above, its not working.

I tried checking if the relevant css file is attached with the element properly (check if the path giving correctly) by changing some other attributes and it worked fine.

With some posts in stack overflow I tried using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css) with all css features included. it shows the vbox element which I was not able to show. But it gives all the output in the bottom of the page. 
Jquery version used is jquery-1.3.2.min.js. 
Anything I'm missing ???

Comment: may be to  old jquery ? 1.8.0  is current stable

Comment: try .toggle instead of .show and see what happens?

Comment: @eicto I have tried with almost all jquery versions, no change.

Comment: @AbiusX No change by using toggle :(
Anyways, Thanks guys.

Comment: how you style it in another css ? by class or by id ?

Comment: by class this is the exact class definition '.b { background-color:white; border:1px solid #BABABA; margin:5px; padding:4px; display:none  }'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that XUL box elements use different value of the CSS `display` property. They use proprietary `-moz-box` instead of `block`, because they have to be flexible boxes. Jquery's `show()` method sets `display: block`, which kind of works in XUL, but not quite.

So, to make it work correctly, you should do this to show an XUL box element:

```
myElement.style.display = '-moz-box';
```